# To connect vertices?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
I chose Vertex and tried to add a line by pressing F button. But if i connecting to another location,i creating a line that's out of the edge, just like in the picture. I thought my methods were wrong, but no one could fix them.

add I've added pictures, and I want to correct the fact that the lines in the middle don't apply at all.

Comment: Please update your question to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish and what steps you have taken so far. What are you trying to do with the 2 vertices? Also, please try to update your English grammar so that it is easier to understand what you are saying.

That being said, try using the Fill function with 3 or more vertices connected (F on the keyboard).

Comment: i try to do make lines but the line is not be not precisely connected to the faces

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are doing here, but it looks like you are trying to divide that n-gon up.

The knife tool is <kbd>k</kbd>, with it active click the first vertex, then the next.  This should result in the polygon being split along the resulting edge in the way you expect.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so rude to ask.I tried to connect to each other by choosing a vertex, and if I check it on the edge, it's not properly connected between the sides.I thought it was my way or my way of doing it wrong, but no way could fix it or do it.

Comment: Its still not quite clear what you are trying to do sal.

Answer (score 0):

To create a single edge you need to merge two of the vertices together using the **Merge menu**  ( keyboard shortcut **Alt M** ) . See the screenshot below :

[image]

Editing the above image because looking more closely there is no vertex at that position A.
New image below:

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry i think My question was very bad i updated question please check again thanks you

Comment: Its still not quite clear what you are trying to do sal. If you are very new to Blender then i would suggest you start your model again and this time make sure your model is using only Quads or triangles. Quads are faces made with only 4 vertices and tris are faces faces with only 3 vertices. When you get to the problem stop. take some scree, shots and also post the .blend file so we can take a look and better understand what you are trying to do :) Use the following link to upload your .blend file .

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @3fingeredfrog please avoid putting the core of text for an answer as part of the images. It is not editable that way and search engines cannot read into them, which might make the information less accessible.